# Remote Link on OSX

Tags: filesystems, mac-osx, symbolic-link, hardlink

I have two machines on the same LAN, I usually ssh from one to the other and I was wondering if I could create a symbolic or hard link from a box that points to the other one.

I'm using OSX on both PC's

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can have a symbolic link if you will use nfs/smb/afp to mount a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an icon that opens the SSH shell? or a file link that opens the finder to the other machine's hard drive?

For a SSH shell icon you can make a text file that contains the ssh command and change its name to something.command.

For a remote folder you can add a symbolic link that points to a mounted folder.

```
# ln -s {path} {linkname}
```

I think you can do something functionally equivalent to the later using the finder and adding the remote folder to the dock or sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a directory as mounting point an mount the filesystems from the other computer through sshfs and macfuse. for mac osx look at this [site](http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2007/01/19/macfuse-sshfs-for-your-mac/).
you have to download and install the macfuse core dmg and after installation the seperate sshfs dmg.

example mountcommand:

```
/Applications/sshfs/bin/mount_sshfs USER@HOST:DIRECTORY /PATH/TO/YOUR/MOUNTPOINT
```

of course you can't do anything other than filesystem related stuff over this. if you want to start/stop processes or anything like that you have to login through ssh.

- [macfuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/)
- [sshfs (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS)
- [sshfs (fuse)](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html)